# How to use "input" on Linux (Fedora 16)?

Tags: input, texmaker, linux

This seems like a trivial thing, but I can't figure out how to use `input` properly on Fedora. When I used Windows 7, I would put the following into my document

`\input{D:/Dropbox/Code_Library/LaTeX/custom_headings_1.tex}`

The file is now located at `/home/[user_name]/Home/Dropbox/Code_Library/LaTeX/custom_headings_1.tex`

But when I try to use `input{/home/[user_name]/Home/Dropbox/Code_Library/LaTeX/custom_headings_1.tex}` I get a "file not found" error.

In retrospect, since I still use Windows regularly, doing this is probably not a good idea because I won't be able to compile documents on both platforms. Can any one suggest a better file inclusion system than putting a "custom_headings_1.tex" file in every new document's folder?

Comment: Does `[user_name]` have spaces?

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the same file on Windows and on a Unix system can be accomplished by the following code

```
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\ifwindows
  \newcommand{\dropboxprefix}{D:/Dropbox/Code_Library/LaTeX}
\else
  \newcommand{\dropboxprefix}{/home/[user_name]/Home/Dropbox/Code_Library/LaTeX}
\fi
```

and then

```
\input{\dropboxprefix/customheadings_1.tex}
```

should work on both systems.

About TeX not finding the file on the GNU/Linux platform only guesses can be cast: what does the shell command

```
kpsewhich /home/[user_name]/Home/Dropbox/Code_Library/LaTeX/custom_headings_1.tex
```

answer?

Of course in all this `[user_name]` should be replaced by the actual user name.

Comment: As it turns out, my filepath was simply wrong. It was actually /home/[user_name]/Dropbox/Code_Library/LaTeX/custom_headings_1.tex. There is no 'Home', although I could have sworn that there was. Thanks for everyone's help.